# How do I obtain the secret "Chatterbox" achievement?

Tags: achievements, tomb-raider-2013

I was made aware of this secret achievement today, and apparently I've already missed some dialog between Lara and the Endurance crew members. During the course of the game you can actually talk to members of your crew when you meet up with them (I didn't know this and didn't ever try to). When do I have to talk to my crew members in order to hear the extra dialogs and get this achievement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I, too, hadn't heard of this achievement until just now. Luckily, PowerPyx over at [Xbox360Achievements](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/game/tomb-raider-9/achievement/75961-Chatterbox.html) had. He even put together a nice list!

> During the course of the story there are 7 occasions where you can talk to your friends. You will have to listen to everything they have to say. If you miss one single conversation you cannot get this trophy / achievement in your current playthrough anymore. You need to keep talking to everyone until the Square X symbol above their head is gone. You will also see the TR auto-save logo flashing in the bottom right corner of the screen when all conversations with one person are done.
>
> You need to talk to the following people:
>
> - Before searching for 50 pieces of salvage, talk to Whitman.
> - After finding the 50 pieces of salvage, talk to Whitman again (do not repair the Axe yet!)
> - After helping Roth (where the wolves attack him), talk to Roth.
> - Shortly after getting the Rope Arrows you will meet Roth again. Talk to him before using the zipline.
> - When reaching the shipwreck beach you will meet your friends. Talk to Sam, Reyes and Jonah.
> - Before going to the Endurance to help Alex and get the tools, talk to Whitman, Sam, Jonah and Reyes at the beach camp. Reyes is on the boat.
> - After coming back from the Endurance, talk to Whitman, Reyes and Jonah.

He's also detailed the entire thing on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9flCTdLqO8).

One thing worth mentioning is that, if you have 50 salvage *before* speaking to Whitman the first time, it *should* give you all of the conversation options before you upgrade your axe, meaning you would be finished after clearing all of the dialogue with him (the chat option stops appearing).

Unfortunately, the achievement *is* missable, meaning you won't be able to get it without playing through the game again (assuming you've already missed one or two, that is).

Comment: Please tell me this achievement isn't available on Steam. The only part of this I missed (when I wasn't even actively trying to get an achievement) is at the second last step - I only spoke to Jonah, neglecting to find and harass the rest of the crew.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro It is! =D Good news! You get to fall through exploding fires all over again!

Comment: [So it is.](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/TombRaider/achievements) And apparently it's just as secret - it's mentioned but there is no description on how to attain it.

Comment: Well, I just talked to Whitman about 4-5 times, then found 50 salvage and now I'm standing next to him and I cannot talk to him again

Comment: @Martin Did you have 50 salvage before you spoke to him the first time?

Comment: No, I had 10 or maybe 20. I spoke to him for as long as was possible, then I set off to find more salvage, I had maybe 100 when I approached him second time, but no dialogue option came up.

Comment: ...Wow, so you can't get it if you had already gone looking for salvage before talking to him?  Pretty stupid that the game **punishes** you for doing the optional stuff.

Comment: @BlueRaja No. That was the initial thought, but my answer addresses that.