# Are some of the challenges/treasures possible to miss forever?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

First off, after I finished the story for Tomb Raider, I went back and started collecting everything and completing challenges.  I decided to make it a personal goal to get 100% of everything in this game without the help of any online guides or tips.  Unfortunately, after spending a ridiculous amount of time searching for just a few last things I need, I'm starting believe I forever missed them because I didn't get them during the story, and there are some areas I can no longer seem to get to.

Without telling me where anything is or how to get them, let me tell you what I'm looking for and if possible, please just let me know whether "yes" it is still possible to get them or "no" it's too late after finishing the story.

I'm looking for the last two mines on Shipwreck Beach.  I didn't get any during the story, and I feel like I've searched everywhere dozens of times and I'm still missing two.  There's a section of Shipwreck Beach I can no longer seem to reach (because one of the gondolas you jump on during the story had fallen) and I feel like maybe two of the mines are past that point.  I don't really know.

Another thing I can't seem to get is a document, which according to the map is located on the Endurance.  It doesn't look like there is any way for me to get back onto the ship any more.

So please, don't tell me how to get these or where the mines are.  If you can just let me know if it's still possible to get them, I'll keep trying on my own.  Otherwise I won't waste my time.

Thanks!

Hmmmm...  I suppose it would be okay if you also told me whether or not either of those two "unreachable" locations is still reachable.  Just don't tell me if it's necessary!  Thanks again.

Comment: I've done a partial answer to your question, but there's one thing I don't undertand. Which gondolas are you referring to? You should be able to reach every place in the beach, even the Endurance.

Comment: I'm stuck at 6/10 mines myself at the beach. Quite a few people seem to be experiencing a bug that either counts too little of the exploded mines, or puts them in unreachable places.

Comment: @Kappei, In the northern part of Shipwreck Beach, there are a couple of gondolas you jump across on the way to the Research Base.  You use the rope puller to do move them closer to you as you do this.  After you jump from the second one, it falls from the cable.  Because of this, when you return later, you can no longer get to the northern-most part of Shipwreck Beach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, none of the challenges and treasures can be missed forever. The developers have been careful on not putting any of this kind of content in the "one time only" zones. They've done a great work, instead, in hiding in plain sight your goals. As you should already know, all of the "Challenge" content doesn't show on the map, even with every ability unlocked, so you'll have to explore every inch of the map to find what you're looking for.

About the mines, you should search for them in the sea mostly, possibly behind rocks and eventually only reachable with your weapons (zooming can help).

You should be able to reach the document too, since it should be in the part of the Endurance that

> didn't sink after the explosion.

Comment: "They've done a great work, instead, in hiding in plain sight your goals." Mmph hrhrrmph.

Comment: Thank you.  This really borders are 'too much info' but I already saw Keith's answer below, which seems to spoil the location of the remaining mines for me.

Oh, one thing, though.  I went to the area closest to the Endurance, and I didn't see any ropes or anything that would allow me to reach it.  I'll look again, though.  Also, when I went there, a bug occurred that caused all of the ocean water textures to disappear, so maybe something relating to that bug made it hard to see.  I'll look again.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry if these informations were too much, I tried to be as generic as possible. I can assure you though that, even with what you have now, those mines will still be hard to find. Good luck!

Comment: Oh yeah, I thought I would let you know that the missing textures issue near the Endurance **was** the problem, as the rope was also missing.  When I went back again everything was there and I was able to get back onto the ship.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have 100% and every challenge is still reachable after game completion.

The sea mines are one of the toughest, mainly because a couple are out to sea far enough that they don't glow when you use survival vision. They're only visible during the low part of each wave.

The section of Shipwreck Beach that you jump across cable cars to get to can't be reached again, but it has no challenges. They're all in the Research Base.

After the quest in the Endurance you can still zip line back to the rear of the boat by the same route you used before.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I wish you hadn't told me the mines were out to sea.  You should have just told me that I can still get them if I keep looking.  Now I kinda feel like I've been spoiled.

Comment: @vertigoelectric apologies if that is too much, but as the level is  mostly sea I didn't think that was giving too much away. Even once I knew the 'trick' of spotting them (no glow and hidden by waves) it took me a _long_ time to find them all

Comment: after your clues, I was able to find the last two very quickly.  It is kind of annoying that they don't glow.  I don't think it has to do with distance, either, because objects farther away would still glow.  Anyway, I still appreciate your answer.  I just don't feel right about saying I completed it without help now.  :(  So close, too.  I got absolutely everything else without any assistance whatsoever.

Comment: All the sea mines were glowing when I played. Perhaps it got patched. Also they're called "sea mines" - you'd expect to find them in the sea.

Answer (score 3):

Though others have mentioned that no challenges or treasures are missable, I'd like to note that some achievements *are* missable.  I know of two:

- [Boom Goes the Dynamite](http://www.ign.com/wikis/tomb-raider/Boom_Goes_the_Dynamite): Shoot a thrown explosive out of the air.
- [Chatterbox](http://www.ign.com/wikis/tomb-raider/Chatterbox): Talk with all crew members of the Endurance *([See also](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/107826))*.

Also, there's a bug that makes it possible to miss the "Tomb of the Lost Adventurer" DLC.  See [How do I work around the game-breaking “Tomb of the Lost Adventurer” DLC bug?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125701)