# How do I work around the game-breaking "Tomb of the Lost Adventurer" DLC bug (can't climb plane)?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

I've had to restart this area three times now due to a bug that prevents completion - on the PC, if you burn the trees in the order that you're **supposed to**, the plane breaks incorrectly and you cannot complete the DLC.

I've found a few links ([1](http://tombraiders.net/stella/walks/TR9walk/details/lost-adventurer.html), [2](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=136114)) that claim to have workarounds, but they're very unclear *(eg. "Start with the right-most fire" does not help, as there are two rightmost fires!)*

Also, apparently Eidos [believes they fixed this issue](http://forums.eidosgames.com/showthread.php?t=133823), but they definitely have not, as I just today encountered it (PC, Steam version, latest update).

So, **what order do I have to light the fires to work around this bug?**

Comment: I had this just yesterday. Quite annoying having just paid for DLC which I now cannot play.

Comment: I just went back tonight and the tree didn't block my way, I could walk right through it. It allowed me to complete the tomb. I didn't start again, just completed a few game sections and fast travelled back.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to complete tomb after just stepping outside of it and coming back in, You will hear a distinctive tone indicating you've left the tomb, at that moment you can turn around and the glitchy part in the plane seems to have resolved itself in your absence.